# Laravel 4 Public Functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a question. I made a function that says if 'type' (a column in my database) is equal to five, it'll display buttons that others can't view. The problem is when I log out or log into a user that doesn't have type equals to five, it displays an error. How could I do this in a function? I tried various things, but it always displays errors. Here's my method...

```
<?php

public function get_dash()
{
    $roles = Auth::user()->type;

    if ($roles == '5') {
        return View::make('admin.dash')->with('roles', $roles);
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('news/index')
            ->with('danger', 'You either have insufficient permissions 
                   to access this page or your user credentials 
                   are not refreshed.');
    }
}
```

I basically want it so that if no type equals to five in an account, or when I log out it'll load normally...

```
return View::make('news/index');
```

Comment: What error is it displaying?

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro
it says the error is in $roles = Auth::user()->type; , when I view it as a guest, error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to access the User object, check to make sure that the user is in fact authenticated by using Auth::check() as specified in the [manual](http://four.laravel.com/docs/security).

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user is not authenticated, you have no access to ´Auth::user()´, so you need something like this:

```
public function get_index()
{
    if( ! Auth::guest() ) 
    {
        $roles = Auth::user()->type;

        return View::make('aac.index')
                ->with('newss', News::all())
                ->with('roles', $roles);
    }
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have two almost same codes. This one was placed in MainController: 

http://paste.laravel.com/FZg

I've edited basing on your answer and it says: `This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost:8000/news/index has resulted in too many redirects. ` I want the guest to view the index, but can only acess the admin dashboard when their 'type' is equals to 5.

Comment: It is redireding to the same page always, so Redirect to login, or just render a view that says to your user that login is mandatory... Just edited.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. Thank you anyway, used the Auth::check().