# Laravel 4 view composers not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I saw this question. I have a similar problem, but it ain't working. [Laravel 4 public functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025701/laravel-4-public-functions).

I have a view composer that includes some codes in base layout. Here's my composer:

```
View::composer(array('common.menu_addition','common.base_errors','common.view_special'), function($view)
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $roles = Auth::user()->type;
        if ($roles == '5') {
            $view->with('roles', $roles);
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('news/index');
        }
    }
});
```

When I'm not logged in, it works perfectly. But one of my files of view composer goes like this:

```
    <div class="pull-right">
 @if (Auth::check())
                    @if ($roles == 5)

                      <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                          <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/dash') }}">
                            <i class="icon-eye-open">
                            </i>

                            <strong>
                              Admin Dashboard
                            </strong>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>

                        @endif
                        @endif
                      </div>
```

When I login, it won't display any site. It just says `Undefined variable: roles` in that view composer file.

Comment: I don't think that return will work with view composer, as view::composer is only used to pass data to views

Comment: @TryingTobemyself

I just want it to have roles for every website I load, and to load the view I posted. When I'm logged out it works fine, but when I log in I get the errors.

Comment: Can post the exact error? On which line you get error?

Comment: @TryingTobemyself
The exact error is `Undefined variable: roles` in my view file that I've posted in my question, the line is 23., or where it says `@if ($roles == 5)`

Comment: are there any other roles in your app?

Comment: @TryingTobemyself
No, I've used User.php(model) and added protected `$table = 'accounts';`. There is an column called `type` in my accounts table. I had it working on my other project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to return a redirect like that, in your view composer. And even if you could it's a bad place to put that logic. You should create a filter http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing and redirect away if the user doesn't have the proper authentication level.

Comment: I already have one: `Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) 
    {
        $roles = Auth::user()->role;

        if ($roles == '5') 
        {
            return Redirect::to('news/index')->with('roles', $roles);
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        return View::make('errors.401');
    }
});` And then, do I need a view composer? Also, how could I make the `$roles = Auth::user()->type;` go to every site I load? Will the view I posted in my question work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not defining $roles beforehand and not passing $roles into your views.

When you're making checks against the $roles in views you need to make sure that variable actually exists. Other possibility is to change the check to something like

```
@if (isset($roles) && $roles == 5)
```

to ignore the error but that gets really messy in the long run.

So make sure to initialise view variables beforehand in the view composer and everywhere else. Laravel tries to be much more stricter about non-initialised variables than PHP in common.